# ASP.net Formmailer

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a formmailer using ASP.net C#. Does anybody know of a good tutorial that I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a reasonable tutorial - might almost provide too much detail:

http://www.webreference.com/programming/asp/ASP_Net_Form/index.html

Comment: This was an awesome reference.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/SelfConfigFormMailer.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx

Or you can look for an answer [here...](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=c%23+asp.net+formmailer&meta=&aq=f&oq=)

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Request.Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985.aspx) and [MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) classes. These should get you started.